# Input value not changing when using Redux

Tags: redux

I am trying to build a simple React app which uses Redux for state management. I am able to create a store and dispatch actions but cannot figure out why the displayed value of input is not updated.

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sound-gbln06?file=/src/App.js)

I have a separate *reducer.js* & *App.js*. Both are below.

```
// This is App.js file
import "./styles.css";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import myReducer from "./reducers/reducer.js";

const store = createStore(myReducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("current state", store.getState());
});

export default function App() {
  function updateFName(event) {
    let action = { type: "UPDATE_FIRST_NAME", payload: event.target.value };
    store.dispatch(action);
  }

  function updateLName(event) {
    let action = { type: "UPDATE_LAST_NAME", payload: event.target.value };
    store.dispatch(action);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        Hello {store.getState().fName} {store.getState().lName}
      </h1>
      <input
        value={store.getState().fName}
        onChange={updateFName}
        placeholder={"Fisrt Name"}
      />
      <input
        value={store.getState().lName}
        onChange={updateLName}
        placeholder={"Last Name"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// This is reducer.js file
const initialState = {
  fName: "",
  lName: ""
};

function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_FIRST_NAME":
      return { ...state, fName: state.fName + action.payload };
    case "UPDATE_LAST_NAME":
      return { ...state, lName: state.lName + action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default myReducer;
```

When I type something in the input fields (red circled in image), I do get the updated store state logged in console( green circled in image). **But the value displayed does not change.** How

[image]

I tried reading other answers but still can't figure it out. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your current component is not getting rerendered. Your component gets rerendered when "state" or the "props" of the component changes.

In redux app, we usually wrap the top level component with

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

then with `useSelecter` hook, we access the state and if any change is detected, `useSelector` rerenders the app so our component gets the latest data from the store. Since you just want to see the basic features of redux,I will show you how to make your component rerenders so you see the issue. in `App.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState();
```

in `onChange` handler, you are updating the redux store, but in this case let's also update the local state

```
 <input
    value={store.getState().fName}
    onChange={(e) => {
      updateFName(e), 
      setFirstName(e.target.value);
    }}
    placeholder={"Fisrt Name"}
  />
```

Since `setFirstName` will update the `useState` value, your component will rerender and you will see the updated values from the store.

Comment: Thanks! "useSelector" approach worked. 
In the second approach why do I need to create a state with useState if I already have the store? Isn't that the whole point of store so that we can eliminate multiple states in each and every component?

Comment: @AshutoshGupta the reason i used ‘useState’ to prove you that you were not getting updated state values because your component was not rerendering. By changing ‘useState’ value, i had component rererendered so you could see the updated value in your component

Comment: Also, even though you have redux store, you still sometimes need local state using ‘usestate’. In your case it is not necessary. It was just for demonstration purpose

Answer (score 1):

I think the general best practice here is to use local state for the input `value`s and then submit your updates to the redux state store with on `onClick` handler in a button. That way you can do any validations that you need to before the data gets added to the state store. Something roughly like:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const Form = () => {
  const [fName, setFName] = useState('');

  const validateForm = () => {
    let validForm = true;

    // Do some checks here using fName and set to false if invalid data
    if (fName === '') {
      validForm = false;
    }

    return validForm;
  }

  const submitForm = (event) => {
    // Prevents the submit button from refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();

    // Validate for required fields; Returns true if input data is valid
    const validForm = validateForm();

    if (validForm) {
      // Copied from your code above
      let action = { type: "UPDATE_FIRST_NAME", payload: fName };
      store.dispatch(action);
    }
  }

  return (
    <input
      value={fName}
      onChange={(event) => setFName(event.target.value)}
    />
    <button onClick={event => submitForm(event)}>Submit</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to create states for each component which in turn get value form store? Is this the industry standard? If yes, that means we are duplicating data and store will no longer be the single source of truth. Right?

Comment: Yes, it’s a pretty general practice: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#dispatching-actions-with-usedispatch